# Weird behaviour with fwrite

Tags: c, memory, save, buffer, fwrite

I'm trying to save a struct into a file. It works fine and I can load it without any problem. But when I'm inspecting my save file with a hex editor, I can see some parts of a previous printf stored in the file. I really don't understand how this is possible, especially when my program works totally fine to load the struct.

I have three structs (Orientation, ShipType, Status and PlayerType are enumerations, you can replace them by Int) :

```
struct Map
{
    int width, height;
    int* cases;
};
typedef struct Map Map;

struct Ship
{
    int x, y, length, firstShoot, color;
    int hasBeenDiscovered;
    Orientation orientation;
    ShipType type;
    Status status;
};
typedef struct Ship Ship;

struct Player
{
    int activeShips;
    Map map[2];
    char lastMoves[5][128];
    Ship ships[10];
    PlayerType type;
    int shipcolor[4];
    int color;
};
typedef struct Player Player;
```

Here is the tree of my program :

main() -> playMenu() -> actionMenu() -> save()

Here is a screen of one of my menus (`playMenu()`)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBQ9P.jpg

The printf part I'm talking about is just this :

```
    printf("=========== BATAILLE NAVALE ===========\n"); // You can see part of "=======" in my save file
    printf("        ~~~~Jouer une partie~~~~\n\n");
    printf("1. Joueur contre joueur\n");
    printf("2. Joueur contre ordinateur\n");
    printf("3. Charger une partie\n\n"); // You can see "partie"
    printf("0. Quitter\n"); // You can see "0. Quitter"

    printf("\nVotre choix : "); // You can see "Votre choix"
    scanf("%d", &choix);
```

And here is the screen of a chunk of my file seen through an hex editor

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgKXG.jpg

You can clearly see that some of my menus are written in that file. How is this possible ?
Unfortunately, I can't post any more code because I would have to post so much but do you have any idea what might cause this and where I need to look in order to fix this ?

Here is the code of my `save()` function, you can see that it has nothing to do with those menus :

```
int save(Player players[2], int currentPlayer)
{
    int* i;
    FILE* file = NULL;

    file = fopen("save.txt","w+");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(players, sizeof(Player), 2, file);

        fwrite(players[0].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[0].width * players[0].map[0].height, file);
        fwrite(players[0].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[1].width * players[0].map[1].height, file);
        fwrite(players[1].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[0].width * players[1].map[0].height, file);
        fwrite(players[1].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[1].width * players[1].map[1].height, file);

        fwrite(&currentPlayer, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: I tried, but I can't manage to reproduce this out of my program. I know you can't give me an exact anwser with such few code, but maybe someone had a problem like this before and can lead me somewhere

Comment: Please show and explain "parts of a previous printf".

Comment: Maybe it's just happen to be uninitialized parts of some arrays?

Comment: Please show the declaration of all involved types. We accept that the problem might not be reproducible at our machines, but we do want all the code involved. So please reconsider making a [mcve].

Comment: The hex in question, does it seem to be written by `fwrite(players, sizeof(Player), 2, file);` ? I get the impression that it can be none of the other written parts.

Comment: Added my structs. @Someprogrammerdude maybe you have the answer. My players' lastMoves aren't initialized. Well I just run `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) strcpy(player->lastMoves[i], "");`, is this a bad way to initialize them ?

Comment: Instead of `strcpy` use just `player->lastMoves[i][0] = '\0'`. It's just the same but without the overhead of calling a function and checking string lengths. And yes that will leave the majority of your arrays uninitialized and with *indeterminate* contents. But that's not a problem unless you *use* that uninitialized data, which hopefully you won't do.